# javascript confirm works not working in chrome or IE, but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, confirm

I tried doing a search in stackoverflow.  There were topics on this issue.  I tried several of the fixes that were close to mine, but none of the worked.  I also tried Googling the topic, but anything I tried did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the situation, this javascript confirm works, meaaning the confirm dialogue appears and is functional in Firefox, but not work in IE or Chrome, meaning the confirm dialogue box does not appear and the code moves to the appropriate next page as if it were confirmed:

```
function confirmReserve($checkin, $checkout, $nights, $points) { 

    var $in =new Date($checkin*1000);
    var $out =new Date($checkout*1000);
    if (confirm("Your Reservation Details:  \n\nCheck-In Date:  " + $in.toLocaleFormat('%B %d, %Y') + "\nCheck-Out Date:  " + $out.toLocaleFormat('%B %d, %Y')  + "\nTotal Nights:  " + $nights + "\nTotal points:  " + $points + "\n\nClick OK to process reservation.")) {
    return true; 
 }  else {
    return false;
 }
```

But, this one works in all three:

```
function confirmDelete() { 
if (confirm("Click OK to confirm cancellation of your reservation.")) {
    return true; 
 }  else {
    return false;
 } 
}
```

It is the same PHP program, same browsers.
Here is the HTML to the one that does not work:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirmReserve('<?php echo $InDate;?>', '<?php echo $OutDate;?>', '<?php echo $totalNights;?>', '<?php echo $totalPoints;?>')" action="reservationConf.php">
```

Here is the HTML for the one that does work:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirmDelete()" action="deletereservation.php?ReservationID=' . $Reservation['ReservationID'] . '">
```

Comment: I should have noted, others have tested in all three browsers on different machines with the same result of no confirm dialogue box in IE or Chrome, but get one in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

try to put before your function that code below:

```
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

Date.prototype.toLocaleFormat = Date.prototype.toLocaleFormat ||     
    function(pattern) {
        return pattern.replace(/%Y/g, this.getFullYear())
           .replace(/%m/g, (this.getMonth() + 1))
           .replace(/%B/g, monthNames[this.getMonth()])
           .replace(/%d/g, this.getDate()); 
};
```

The issue is that Chrome and IE are missing toLocaleFormat function, according to [JavaScript function not working on Chrome & IE but works on FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212920/javascript-function-not-working-on-chrome-ie-but-works-on-firefox)